# BIRT Chart is not opened for Haskell EclipseFP profiling run

Tags: haskell, eclipse-plugin, birt, eclipse-fp

I have installed EclipseFP plug-in for Haskell on Eclipse. Everything is fine. I followed instructions from http://eclipsefp.github.com/install.html. My Haskell programs are running there, I have Hoogle help, etc. 
But if I run my Haskell app with profiling it is generating .hp file after it is closed. It is opened then with Default Editor in Text format like:

```
JOB "test4.exe"
DATE "Thu Oct 25 22:29 2012"
SAMPLE_UNIT "seconds"
VALUE_UNIT "bytes"
BEGIN_SAMPLE 0.00
END_SAMPLE 0.00
BEGIN_SAMPLE 0.01
END_SAMPLE 0.01
```

I have already installed BIRT 3.7 Charting. Why it is not opening as I chart. What I missed? I tried to open with another editor, but there is nothing connected with BIRT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should just need BIRT Charting and the BIRT Engine. The name of the editor associated with the profiling output is "Profiling Output Viewer", it should be an option when you do Open With... on the .hp file. (It should also appear if you go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations and check the associated editors for *.hp)

If you don't see the Profiling Output Viewer, check the Eclipse log files for errors. The name of the plugin tasked with opening the BIRT chart is "net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.profiler", search for errors loading that plugin.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Additionally "-rtsopts" should be added to Compiler options in cabal file.